# Ajustar janelas do Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com dor de cabeça danada tentando ajustar as janelas do VS 2017. Fiz alguma besteira que modificou as coisas e tentei refazer, mas só estou dando murro em ponta de faca. Eu tirei o print de como era mais ou menos o meu.

A parte principal no canto esquerdo e o direito tinha o Solution Explorer e o Team Explorer, sendo que o Team Explorer ficava como em Output-Call Stacks-Breakpoints ou em Auto-Autos/Locals e poderia abrir a janela rapidamente sem necessidade de abrir em View.

Na parte de baixo do Solution Explorer eu tinha uma outra janela onde está o Output, mas alinhado corretamente abaixo do Solution Explorer. Tentei fazer o mesmo, mas de maneira alguma consigo fixar naquela parte. Sempre que tento a única solução é fixar na parte inferior tomando toda parte de baixo, que não quero.

E por fim, a outra janela do canto superior esquerdo que deixo como o Output, mas repete a mesma coisa do citado acima.

Como resolver este imbróglio? Agradecido

Comment: Difícil responder isso, é destacando a janela, ir aproximando de onde quer colocar, aparece onde vai encaixar, é mais ou menos como aqueles bloquinhos que se usa no prézinho. O "segredo" é ir passando até ele mostrar o local correto para soltar. Tem algum problema mais específico, só não não consegue encaixar no lugar certo? Não sei se dá para ajudar mais que isso sem ir até fazer para você.

Comment: Entendo esta parte.Tentei ver alguns tutoriais na internet por vídeo, mas nenhum de fato mostra como fazer como quero. 

É possível gravar um vídeo mostrando, por favor? Estou em modo de desespero mesmo lool

Answer (score 0):

Tente isto: Window -> Reset Window Layout
[image: Window -> Reset Window Layout]